# Displaying nothing or default content in the event of no row match using AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, content-builder

I've got a data extension I'm storing content in for templated emails, then referencing the content using AMPscript as below:

```
%%[ SET @MEMBER_EVENTS="MEMBER_EVENTS"
    SET @ITEM_1="ITEM_1" 
    SET @Rows = LookupRows("CONTENT","CATEGORY",@MEMBER_EVENTS,"CONTENT_TYPE", @ITEM_1) 
    IF RowCount(@Rows) > 0 THEN 
    SET @ITEM_1_TITLE = FIELD(ROW(@Rows,1),"TITLE") 
    SET @ITEM_1_DESCRIPTION = FIELD(ROW(@Rows,1),"DESCRIPTION") 
    SET @ITEM_1_URL = FIELD(ROW(@Rows,1),"URL") 
    SET @ITEM_1_IMAGE_URL = FIELD(ROW(@Rows,1),"IMAGE_URL") 
    SET @ITEM_1_BUTTON_TEXT = FIELD(ROW(@Rows,1),"BUTTON_TEXT") 
    ENDIF ]%%
```

This format works fine, but I now want to create an ITEM_1_DISPLAY variable and set this as "NO" in the event that there is no row match. Am I able to tweak the above or would I have to code this differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
%%[ SET @MEMBER_EVENTS="MEMBER_EVENTS"
    SET @ITEM_1="ITEM_1" 
    SET @Rows = LookupRows("CONTENT","CATEGORY",@MEMBER_EVENTS,"CONTENT_TYPE", @ITEM_1) 

    IF RowCount(@Rows) > 0 THEN 
    SET @ITEM_1_TITLE = FIELD(ROW(@Rows,1),"TITLE") 
    SET @ITEM_1_DESCRIPTION = FIELD(ROW(@Rows,1),"DESCRIPTION") 
    SET @ITEM_1_URL = FIELD(ROW(@Rows,1),"URL") 
    SET @ITEM_1_IMAGE_URL = FIELD(ROW(@Rows,1),"IMAGE_URL") 
    SET @ITEM_1_BUTTON_TEXT = FIELD(ROW(@Rows,1),"BUTTON_TEXT") 

    ELSE 
    SET @ITEM_1_DISPLAY = "NO"

    ENDIF ]%%
```

Here's what it will do:

It will try to find rows in your Data Extension, and if the number of rows found is greater than 0, it will assign values from Data Extension fields to all `ITEM_1` variables.
In case it finds 0 rows, it will just assign the value of "NO" to a variable called `@ITEM_1_DISPLAY`.

Comment: Thanks zuzannamj - when I try to show/hide HTML using this variable, for some reason it's not identifying a value of NO for the ITEM_1_DISPLAY variable. I'm using the following:

%%[IF @ITEM_1_DISPLAY == "NO" THEN]%%
&nbsp;

%%[ELSE]%%

SOME HTML

%%[ENDIF]%%

Comment: You can easily test the value by outputting it anywhere in the html, try to add this somewhere after your ampscript block: %%=v(@Item_1_dispaly)=%%

Comment: Thanks - I did do this but nothing was output. In my HTML, IF @ITEM_1_DISPLAY != "NO" THEN SHOW THIS - this shows the text so presumably, the variable is not being set as NO for some reason.

Comment: Can you add the whole code to your original question? And how are you testing this?